# TypeError: this.$route.push is not a function vue.js and Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

i am getting an error like "TypeError: this.$route.push is not a function" even i tried ES6 also to bind this, still not working. whenever I click a button which is "Get Homepage Data" in about.vue it should redirect to home page.  is working but here i need to call ajax and after ajax response only it has to redirect,,, so that i am not using

router.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";
import Home from "../components/Home/Home.vue";
import About from "../components/About.vue";
import FallBackPage from "../components/FallBackPage/FallBackPage.vue";
import MyOrders from "../components/MyOrders/MyOrders.vue";

 Vue.use(Router);

export function createRouter() {
  return new Router({
  mode: "history",
  routes: [
   { path: "/", component: Home },
   { path: "/about", component: About },
   { path: "/myorders", component: MyOrders },
   { path: "/*", component: FallBackPage }
  ]
 });
}
```

main.js

```
 import Vue from "vue";
 import App from "./App.vue";
 import { createRouter } from "./router/router.js";

  export function createApp() {

   const router = createRouter();

   const app = new Vue({
      router,
      render: h => h(App)
  });

 return { app, router };
 }
```

about.vue

```
 <template>
  <div>
    {{ aboutText }}
     <button  @click="gobackToHome">Get Homepage Data</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
   data() {
    return {
      aboutText: "About Component"
    };
  },
  method: {
     gobackToHome: function() {

        this.$route.push("/")

   // $route or $router both are not working


    }

    // gobackToHome: () => {
      //  this.$route.push("/")
     // }

   }

};
</script>
```

Comment: you should set `this.$router.push("/")` you're missing `r`
`

Comment: He said he'd tried both, even though yes it is `router.push`. Think of it like this, `route` is the current route you're on, while `router` is the router itself.

Comment: Try using `this.$router.push({name: ''Home"});` and give your `/` route the name `"Home"`

Comment: Also, try using `@click="$router.push('/')"` directly instead of in the method

Comment: @all not working still

Comment: Try `:to="/"` instead of using `@click`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change route

```
 this.$router.push({ path: '/' })
 this.$router.push({ name: 'Home' })
```

//main.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import { routes } from "./router/router";

Vue.use(VueRouter);
export function createApp() {
  const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: "history",
    routes
   });

  const app = new Vue({
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
  }).$mount("#app");

  return { app, router };
}
```

//routes.js

```
 import Home from "../components/Home/Home.vue";
 import About from "../components/About.vue";
 import FallBackPage from "../components/FallBackPage/FallBackPage.vue";
 import MyOrders from "../components/MyOrders/MyOrders.vue";

 export const routes = [
   { path: "/", component: Home },
   { path: "/about", component: About },
   { path: "/myorders", component: MyOrders },
   { path: "/*", component: FallBackPage }
 ]
```

on top of main.js changes to change route we need to use the following

```
 this.$router.push({ path: '/' })
 this.$router.push({ name: 'Home' })
```

Answer (score 7):

I think the issue is you aren't importing vue-router into your app. Only into router.js and then you don't import all of router.js into your app, only the createRouter function. Try this:

```
//routes.js

import Home from "../components/Home/Home.vue";
import About from "../components/About.vue";
import FallBackPage from "../components/FallBackPage/FallBackPage.vue";
import MyOrders from "../components/MyOrders/MyOrders.vue";

export const routes [
   { path: "/", component: Home },
   { path: "/about", component: About },
   { path: "/myorders", component: MyOrders },
   { path: "/*", component: FallBackPage }
  ]




//main.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import {routes} from './routes'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes
})

new Vue({
      router,
      render: h => h(App)
  }).$mount('#app')
```

Then in your component you use `this.$router.push("/")`

Comment: Thanks...some changes i did for your snippet, working upvoted  and my answer also posted